# You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex scheduled jobs

Tags: scheduled-job

Is there any workaround to overcome the above governor limit without aborting the job.

Thanks !

Comment: There is `FlexQueue` but it still in beta as far as I know.

Comment: I'm actually planning on writing an open-source dispatch scheduler that could be used.

Comment: I would at first answer the question, why there are 100 scheduled jobs. That smells of a bad implementation.

Comment: if you used the Dan Appleman async pattern, you would only need one scheduled job but would have unlimited headroom - see: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24448/2602

Comment: @AlexanderJohannes , I've implemented an schedule apex which will  schedule a job to send report as an email to the given mail id depending upon the time given by the user. So if there are 100 users and each want to schedule a report, then how to overcome it ?

Comment: Honestly, having 100+ jobs indicates that design can be improved (especially after working with limited resource in SF for many years). Can report emailing jobs be saved in a Salesforce object, so a batch job can be executed every 15/30 minutes to email users based on pending jobs in the object? In that way, we can have one batch job to handle multiple emailing requests.

Comment: Moreover, wrt using the FlexQueue, the question is how long will "holding" batch jobs be in the queue before they are processed? Does this time depends if the org is sandbox or a Production? https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html --> Re-scheduling itself if there are max active/holding batch jobs might not be good practice either. "Any call to System.schedule inside of a scheduled job will run no sooner than five minutes later." 
http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/TlKAT7avRO7UIeL0GvCUcw --> Great presentation at Dreamforce on FlexQueue

Comment: @RadDeveloper,  Here i've implemented a batch class to run every hour and it schedules 100 jobs which should run on next half an hour and as soon as the job runs i am deleting those jobs and then the batch will execute after an hour and then schedules the jobs which should run on next half an hour , this process will continue.. But the problem is what if i've more than 100 records to be scheduled at same time.

Comment: I still do not understand why one report email to a user must be sent in one batch job (I hope you are not using Schedulable for each email request). Can sending 100+ emails be done in one batch job instead? (Batch jobs should be implemented to process group of requests not just one request.)
Maybe implementing the Queueable interface (mesh of @future and batch) is the best approach for this? http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_apex_queueing_jobs.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html

Comment: Otherwise, if you must use one batch job (Database.Batchable) to send one report email to a user, then one option is writing a custom code for a scheduler that will check current active number of batch jobs and if the limit is not exceeded, then queue emailing requests for processing. Otherwise, reschedule itself in x minutes (configurable in Custom Settings). However, this approach is not optimal as noted in above comments.

Comment: @RadDeveloper, I appreciate your time. Here i've more than 10,000 records and each contains different email addresses and report Ids. And i need to generate an excel sheet (Same as reports printable view) based on given report Id of that record and need to send an email with that attachment to the email address containing in corresponding record b/w given range of dates and timing (ie Daily, Weekly, monthly). So I am running a batch class which runs every hour and it retrieves the records which should be executed in that hour and checks which record should be scheduled and it will schedule it.

Comment: @RadDeveloper, Here i am sending emails asynchronously using future calls and i cannot invoke future method in batch class, that is the reason why i am using schedule apex.  Even i can use normal method and send emails synchronously but i am afraid it might hit governor limit if there are huge volume of records.

Comment: I am glad to help out, but I just do not have enough details. I am wondering why emails are not sent in the batch job that generates reports, so one report is sent to many emails at once? Why there should be another async job to send emails?

Comment: @RadDeveloper, Actually my requirement is to generate excel report and send an email with that excel as an attachment, but neither getContent() nor getContentAsPdf() works in batch or schedule apex. that is the reason why i am using normal apex class to generate and send report.

Comment: ok, so the issue is automated generation of PDFs. In that case, I would check into REST API, so calling a function to generate PDF would be then a callout from the batch (limit of 10 callouts in each start/execute/finish). Or call this function from a future job. Then you can have another batch traversing through a table containing these PDFs as attachments and sending emails to specified users. 
There are some issues with passing in the session ID though. Check out more the following links:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AlGoIAK

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/best-way-to-create-pdfs-on-a-schedule
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/apex/send-email-with-generated-pdf-as-attachment-from-trigger
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090ksIAA

Comment: @RadDeveloper, Thanks for the links, I implemented my requirement similar to ( http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/best-way-to-create-pdfs-on-a-schedule ) and everything is working fine. But here while sending an email i am getting the report content which is visible to the user who is running the batch. I must overcome that. ie Need to implement same as Running User functionality.