# Attach dynamic PDF to email in Approval Process

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, approval-process, renderas

I have a requirement in which when record gets approved in approval process, On final approval action an email sends to an user.

I have a visualforce page which is rendered as PDF
I want that visualforce page attached to that email.

How can I achieve this.

Please help me out through this.

--TIA

Comment: [Here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/best-way-to-create-pdfs-on-a-schedule) is a similar SFSE question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you can do this out of the box, you need to implement apex logic using trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a visualforce email template. Also change your existing VF page to apex:component Then include that in the messaging:attachment inside VF-Email template. 
See : [Adding attachments to VF Email Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm)